# Is there any way of retrieving parameters from pytest.parametrize using kwargs?

Tags: python, pytest

Can we catch these arguments using kwargs?

```
@pytest.parameterize("arg1, arg2", [(1, 2), (3,4)])
def test_function(**kwargs):
     ...
```

Comment: Yes, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1769403/what-is-the-purpose-and-use-of-kwargs

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using parametrize for keyword arguments in pytest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23418844/using-parametrize-for-keyword-arguments-in-pytest)